# Print the values from a Graphql API call in console

Tags: javascript, graphql

I`ve been struggeling this a quiet a lot and would appreciate help. I want to be able to print the title value in the console with console.log.

```
`<script>

const url = "***";

const opts = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify({ query: "*[_type == 'post']{ _updatedAt, _createdAt, title}[0]" })
};
fetch(url, opts)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);

</script>`
```

Results I get in console now:

```
{ms: 6, query: "*[_type == 'post']{ _updatedAt, _createdAt, title}[0]", result: {…}}
ms: 6
query: "*[_type == 'post']{ _updatedAt, _createdAt, title}[0]"
result:
title: "Title2"
_createdAt: "2020-07-02T16:28:49Z"
_updatedAt: "2020-07-05T13:16:27Z"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to access the title field of the result object. Try this:

```
fetch(url, opts)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

If result is an object, I'm guessing you need to specify `result` in the log

```js
fetch(url, opts)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data.result))
  .catch(console.error);
```